# BoneCp no suitable driver found Spring 3.1 Hibernate 4.0

Tags: hibernate, spring, oracle11g, driver, bonecp

I'm currently using BoneCP as a connection pool manager since there is no real alternative (c3p0 is dead). I'm using hibernate 4 and spring 3.1 and everything works fine. The only thing that bothers me is the registration of a custom driver, like `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`.

When the application is starting and some information is loaded form the database I get the following message:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:xxx:xxxx

The datasource is registered as follows :

```
<bean id="mainDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" ref="hibernate.connection.driver_class" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" ref="hibernate.connection.url" />
    <property name="username" ref="hibernate.connection.username" />
    <property name="password" ref="hibernate.connection.password" />
    <property name="poolName" ref="hibernate.connection.username"/>
...
</bean>
```

This datasource is then injected into a sessionfactory.

When running this application in a jetty container in eclipse it works perfectly. When deployed on Tomcat 6.x or Websphere 8.x it is unable to find the specified driver.

I have tried to add this driver to the spring datasourcemanager:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" ref="hibernate.connection.driver_class"/>
    <property name="url" ref="hibernate.connection.url"/>
    <property name="username" ref="hibernate.connection.username"/>
    <property name="password" ref="hibernate.connection.password"/>
</bean>
```

This "fixed" my problem, but now I get a connection closed exception when loading data from the database. (at startup). I'm able to use my application, but sometimes this connection closed error occurs again on random moments.

I have seen that the BoneCP team confirmed the first issue as a [BoneCP bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bonecp/+bug/876476) but is has not been committed yet. I have tried to implement the suggested solution from this bug tracker site, but I get the connection closed error again.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was **two** connection configurations - one in hibernate.cfg.xml and second in spring. Hibernate 4.0 now loading connection configuration if it's avalible from hibernate.cfg.xml despite on spring connection config bean presence.

So just remove second connection config from spring or hibernate.cfg.xml